# Причинно-следственная связь

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли будет тут поставить двоеточие, если я выражаю между частями бсп причинно-следственную связь?

Мама приготовила еду: думала, что я голодный

Comment: Двоеточие ставят, когда есть хоть какая-то интрига (так во всех примерах справочника, а их очень много), то есть хочется спросить почему, а здесь её ноль.